# Bell's quantum nonlocality and finite elements

Tags: numerical-methods, quantum-mechanics, finite-element-method

Nonlocality theorem concerns writing a covariance as $C(a,b)=\int A(a,x)A(b,x)dx$ with A in {1,-1}.

This is not without remembering the weak formulation of FEM with a continuous basis index a or b.

But as quantum mechanics shows this is not always possible and one shall write $A(a,b,x)$ according to mainstream.

How would this be implemented in finite element method basis functions ? Does this mean somehow that the basis functions "know" with which other function it will be multiplied and integrated ?